# Error in using CASE MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have come upon some code and I modified it to new column names.  I have checked several times for spelling issues, but to no avail.

```
UPDATE `company_playtime` 
SET front_player_count = CASE 
    WHEN (front_paid + 1) > front_player_count THEN (front_paid + 1) 
    ELSE front_player_count 
END;
```

This code gives an error:

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'front_player_count' in 'field list'

I am using codeigniter and php with this, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: This may sound like a simplistic question, but does `front_player_count` exist in `company_playtime`?

Comment: does your table have a field called `front_player_count ` ?

Comment: yes, that is what I am so confused about

Comment: So, for some reason I needed to add the Database name to the query.  I am not sure why, but it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try using GREATEST instead?  i.e.

```
UPDATE `company_playtime`
SET front_player_count = GREATEST( front_player_count , front_paid + 1 )
```

Or better yet, just don't update the unaffected rows

```
UPDATE `company_playtime`
SET front_player_count = front_paid + 1
-- use of <= negates requirement for +1 here, should be more efficient
WHERE front_player_count <= front_paid
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

This assumes the columns mentioned do exist within `company_playtime`

Comment: Had you actually made sure to USE the correct database before starting? None of your names were reserved names

Comment: I am working on an existing system, so I assumed that they were using the database that I was expecting.  Bad assumption on my part.  Thanks for your help.